# WebBrowser Control behaving different in two application

Tags: flash, browser, activex, controls

I have two applications.  In one application the web browser control shows a flash movie that is embedded and in the other it does not, only shows place holder.  I have identical code in both constructors to load a web control dynamically and then navigate to the requested web page.

I run both application in debug mode from within VS2010.

Does anyone know why this could happen or know what I have to look for?

Regards
Jaco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found the problem and the solution.

The one project was set to target x86 and the other "any platform".  This meant that when installed on 64bit OS the application uses the 64bit version of the browser (control)... and guess what, flash is not supported in 64bit yet.

Solution:
Either change the target platform in your project OR install the beta of flash 64bit from ([Adobe Flash Player "Square"](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10/))

Regards
Jaco